# I am trying to send email using laravel and i am getting this error "stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587"

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run user email verification in my laravel app.

But i keep getting this error

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
```

I have this in my .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=username@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

did you turned on the "allow less secure app" in your google account? it must be on

Comment: i had that error too.i watched a video on youtube from an indian guy and solved it. but cant remember link.. search how to send email in youtube it will help you